# Adding custom layout to listview in android not recognized

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, layout

I am trying to add a custom layout to my listview where I am calling:

```
mylistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, carList);
```

I was told I am able to replace the simple_list_item_single_choice with a custom xml.  I made a xml and added it to the layout folder in my project and called it mytextview.xml, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:paddingTop="2dip"
android:paddingBottom="3dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="2dp" />
```

My issue is that when I go to change simple_list_item_single_choice to mytextview, it does not find my custom layout file.  Anybody have any idea how to correct this?

Comment: Can you attach the code how are you changing the layout?

Comment: Is mytextview your custom layout ??

Comment: check this.http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Yes mytextview is the custom layout, to change the layout I was just trying to replace the single_list_item with the custom one (mytextview) but I don't see how to recognize it in the android.R.layout.

Comment: just do like this, `mylistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.mytextview, carList);` no need to get via `android.R.layout`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code

```
mylistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, carList);
```

With this

```
mylistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, carList);
```

I hope this will help you.